# Audio change image play/pause javascript

Tags: javascript

I have the following code for playing audio files. When I click on a song, all others must stop. This works but the image only changes when the same song is playing or paused. When I click another song however, the previous song is paused.

I would like the previous image to change from pause to play. Can you help me? I have a foreach loop for this song.

You can try it here: http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/index_mobil.php

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    var currentsound;
    function play_pause(player) {
    var myAudio = document.getElementById(player);
        if(myAudio.paused) {
        myAudio.play();
        } else{
        myAudio.pause();
        }
        $("audio").on("play", function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    $("audio").each(function(i,el){
        if(!$(el).is(_this))
            $(el).get(0).pause();
    });
});
                                }
    function changeImage(img) {
    var imgfile = img.src.split(/\s+/).pop();   
    if (imgfile =="http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/pause1.png" ) 
    {
        img.src = "http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/play1.png";
    }
    else 
    {
        img.src = "http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/pause1.png";
    }
                    }
</script>

<audio id="myAudio<?= $song['id'] ?>" src="http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/store/<?php print $song["file"]; ?>" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:8px; margin-top:4px;">
<img src="http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/play1.png" width="17" height="17" border="0" onclick="play_pause('myAudio<?= $song['id'] ?>');changeImage(this)">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May be on this way:

```
 <script type="text/javascript"> 
    var currentsound;
    var currentimg;
    function play_pause(player,img) {
    if ( currentimg ){
        currentimg.src = "http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/play1.png";
    }
    var myAudio = document.getElementById(player);
        if(myAudio.paused) {
        myAudio.play();
        img.src = "http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/play1.png";
        } else{
        myAudio.pause();
        img.src = "http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/pause1.png";
        }
        $("audio").on("play", function(){
    var _this = $(this);
    $("audio").each(function(i,el){
        if(!$(el).is(_this))
            $(el).get(0).pause();
    });
    currentimg = img;
});
                                }

</script>

<audio id="myAudio<?= $song['id'] ?>" src="http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/store/<?php print $song["file"]; ?>" type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
<div style="float:left; margin-right:8px; margin-top:4px;">
<img src="http://mp3-musicon.de/mp3_download/images/playbuttons/play1.png" width="17" height="17" border="0" onclick="play_pause('myAudio<?= $song['id'] ?>',this); ">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This code is a shorter version of mine. When I switch the song, of the previous song the pause button remains active. but he should switch to play, you understand?